# Action Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

i want to send a parameter "Sportler" to my new-action, there I want to create a new Object of this type.

You can see the error message below.

View:

```
<%= link_to 'New Sportsmen', :action => "new(:type => "Sportler")" %>
```

Controller: trainerones

```
def new
@trainerones = Person.new(:type => params[:type])

    respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @trainerones }
end
```

I get this:

```
G:/testmud/app/views/trainerones/show.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT,           expecting ')'
 ...ler', :action => "new("Sportler")" );@output_buffer.safe_con..
```

And the action is not callable with new_trainerones_path, where can i register this helper?

Now im using new.

Therefor i added: match 'trainerones/new' => 'trainerones#new'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to 'New Sportsmen', "/trainerones/new?type=Sportler" %>
```

Comment: sounds good, No route matches {:action=>"new?type=Sportler", :controller=>"trainerones"}

Comment: Yea,  incomplete answer, I fixed it